# How can change sender to other user?

Tags: docusignapi

when we create docusign account we can add more users. By defaul Sender is email used to create the account. But I need to change the Sender to other user. So the recepient see the changed sender email and name in the email received.

Answer (score 1):

After adding more users with the right permissions, you can log out and log in as the desired user (new sender) and create/send envelopes.